# Syntax errors in ls after update from SVN

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

We are using SVN for version control of code from notes databases. These databases contains a lot of ls/js/java code. For js/java code it works fine.

The problem is with ls libraries. There are at least a hundred of them and they are interconnected. Sometimes if developer submits a ls code change to SVN and then someone else tries to update his copy of database he is getting a lot of syntax errors in notes client. The changed library does not even open properly in old editor and ls code is stored inside field oddly named $ScriptLib_error.

This problem goes away after the developer removes assosiation with on-disk project and than connects the db back to it.

Has anybody else encountered this problem? Are there any feasible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Designer are you using? There were many fixes for source control issues (in particular in the area of LS script lib import) added to 853 Fix Pack 2. If you are not on that fix pack please upgrade to it.